# Custom filter with wildcard tag not working as expected?

Tags: bug, custom-filters

I created a custom filter using a tag wildcard with another tag - I wanted every question that comes up with the keyword in the wildcard where it also has the second tag.  However the results I get aren't as I'd expect.

For example I wanted questions tagged `labeling` that also included a tag containing `arcgis`

[image]

However, as you can see from the results, I'm getting questions with `arcgis` even if they don't have a `labeling` tag - it's almost like it's setting the filter like

```
(labeling and arcgis-desktop) or (arcgis-10.0) or (arcgis-10.1)
```

etc. instead of doing `labeling` with everything `arcgis`

[image]